# Firestore/Flutter: Iterating through the ID of a collection of documents and output them as a list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write a code that outputs the document id of each document within a document that is in a collection that the `StreamBuilder` is subscribed to.

My Firestore structure is this:

- 2020-2021 (Collection)

  - MyClass (Document)

    - Scores (Collection)

      - Quiz 1 (these are the document ids of the documents)
      - Quiz 2
      - Quiz 3

My code might seem complicated but what I'm trying to achieve in a nutshell, is to output the document ids of all documents in a collection (Scores) into a list, while the `StreamBuilder` is subscribed to the changes of the document collecting (MyClass) the collection. However, it gives me this error: [NoSuchMethodError: 'doc', method not found, Receiver: null, Arguments:[]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDHIz.png) I think I'm having a syntax error, but I have no idea how to correct it. I'm also not sure whether the use of the `map` method is correct.

```
    classname = "MyClass";
    CollectionReference schoolYear =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("2020-2021");
    
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: StreamBuilder(
        builder: (context, streamSnapshot) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: DataTable(
              columns: streamSnapshot.data.doc.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return new DataColumn(label: Text(document.id));
              }).toList(),
              rows: <DataRow>[],
            ),
          );
        },
        stream: schoolYear.doc(classname).snapshots(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here's the full error log (after changing to Thavamani's code):
[image: Error Log]

Answer (score 0):

Your current listener `schoolYear.doc(classname).snapshots()` listen to the  changes made on your document `MyClass` and it doesn’t carries it's sub-collection `Scores` details.

To get all document IDs inside `Scores` collection, you can have either stream/future that gets all the documents available in the collection.

Ex, stream builder way

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: StreamBuilder(
        builder: (context, streamSnapshot) {
           if (streamSnapshot.hasError) {
              // print() you could check errors here
              return Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 60,
              );
           } else if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
               return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: DataTable(
                  columns: streamSnapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  return new DataColumn(label: Text(document.documentID));
                 }).toList(),
                rows: <DataRow>[],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return SizedBox(
                 child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                 width: 60,
                 height: 60,
            );
        }
        stream: schoolYear.doc(classname).collection('Scores').snapshots(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

- If you don't want to listen to the documents, simply go with future builder using the `collection('Scores').getDocuments()` instead of `collection('Scores').snapshots()`

Comment: Sorry but this still doesn't work... I still get the NoSuchMethodError:'document' error. I guess maybe there's a problem with the syntax?

Comment: Check all collection names.. and any errors now?

Comment: Could you share full error log?? Specific line would help much..

Comment: Added to the post. I couldn't paste the whole error log because it would output some weird characters. Thank you! (P.S. I have imported both `package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart` and `package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart`

Comment: ok, you have to check snapshot state before getting data from it. updated my code. For more ref - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: And anothe change it did was, `streamSnapshot.data.documents.map()` to `streamSnapshot.data.docs.map()`. Actually I am not sure, which one to go with because for me `.documents` worked; and it seems, it varies with latest version; you may have to use any one of the above;